# woocommerce flash sale - warning division by zero

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, warnings

Since updating woocommerce im getting a warning: division by zero error with the below function.

I don't understand why this error wasn't coming up before, currently even with wp debug off the error is still displayed.

```
function 6516_product_sale_flash( $output, $post, $product ) {
    global $product;
    if($product->is_on_sale()) {
        if($product->is_type( 'variable' ) )
        {
            $regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price();
            $sale_price = $product->get_variation_price();
        } else {
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
        }
        $percent_off = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
        return '<span class="onsale">' . 'Save<br>' . round($percent_off) . '%</span>';
    }
}
```

any ideas as to why this is now an issue?

Thanks

Comment: So from the error it seems like `$regular_price` is set to zero. Should regular price set to zero?

Comment: ive done some more digging and $regular_price is zero but only on composite products. im wondering if $product->get_variation_regular_price() doesnt cover composite products?

Comment: also im not getting this error locally with wamp, only on our siteground account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work this one out.

the regular price was zero when using a composite product that wasn't on sale. so I wrapped the line that was erroring with an if statement which has solved the issue;

```
function 6516_product_sale_flash( $output, $post, $product ) {
    global $product;
    if($product->is_on_sale()) {
        if($product->is_type( 'variable' ) )
        {
            $regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price();
            $sale_price = $product->get_variation_price();
        } else {
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
        }

        if ($regular_price > 0) {

        $percent_off = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
        return '<span class="onsale">' . 'Save<br>' . round($percent_off) . '%</span>';

        }

        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```